# Zend Framework: Loading modules from another directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, autoload

Hey there guys, this is my first question on Stack Overflow. I figured this website has helped me alot so I give it a shot as well.

I'm currently working on multiple Zend Framework applications that need to inherit modules from a common module directory. The file structure used is the conventional method (omitting actual names and references to protect application structure):

```
/application1
    /application
        /modules
            /module1
            /module2
            /module3
            /...

/application2
    /application
```

For now i've tried manually autoloading every single module in the bootstrap of Application2 like so:

```
$moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
    array('namespace' => 'Prefix', 'basePath' => path_to_application1_application_modules_modulename)
);
$autoloader->pushAutoloader($moduleLoader);
```

This works, but as you can imagine this becomes quite a tedious work. Now I've also tried setting the common module directory in the FrontController like so:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->addModuleDirectory(path_to_application1_application_modules);
```

But this doesn't seem to Bootstrap any of the modules. Am I forgetting about something important? Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the config `resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"` in your *config.ini* path and then just use the autoloader.

It works for me, I just used modules from another application by changing the path for `resources.frontController.moduleDirectory` in config.ini.

To try it on your configuration, in **application2** config.ini you should put `resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/../application1/application/modules"`

LE:
If you want you modules bootstrapped add in *config.ini* `resources.modules[] = ""` after the line with moduleDirectory. Tried it myself and without this, other modules are not bootstrapped when entering a random module.

Comment: In anyway I try it still doesn't bootstrap my modules. When I debug to see weither the module bootstraps are called, they don't show up. I'm still clueless...

Comment: Hm none of it seems to have effect. You mentioned "then just use the autoloader." How would you suggest I use it? By creating a new module autoloader object and add it to the autoloader? So basicly as I described in the question.

Comment: Oh I have some results now. I get output from the modules now! Now there's only the problem that models don't seem to be loaded. I guess there's no other way to do this then to use the Module Autoloader object?

Comment: Also it still seems bootstraps aren't dispatched. They aren't even loaded. I put in a parse error on purpose but it doesn't fall over it. I do on the other hand get output from my test controller. This is getting weird

Comment: Now you have to put `Zend_Autoloader` at work to register the namespace for that application (considering your models have their classes named after the Zend convention; eg: Module_Model_Something)

Comment: Some extra info. From outputting the result of get_inluded_files() I can see non of the Bootstraps from the modules are included. I have added resources.modules[] = "" as I've been using this from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

When bootstrapping your modules are you doing it as a Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap. It's obvious but the file should also be in the root module folder.